# Scroll to next element ID in an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Currently I'm using angular-scroll for my navigation, as per below, which works perfect with links in the navbar:

```
var ScrollApp = angular.module('myApp.ScrollApp', ['duScroll', 'ngAnimate']).value('duScrollOffset', 60);

ScrollApp.controller('ScrollCtrl', function($scope){
        var container = angular.element(document.getElementById('container'));
        var sectionhome = angular.element(document.getElementById('Home'));
        $scope.toTheTop = function() {
            container.scrollTop(60, 5000);
        };
        $scope.toHome = function() {
            container.scrollTo(sectionhome, 60, 1000);
        };
        $scope.scrollVariable = false;
        $scope.ids = ['Section1', 'Section2', 'Section3'];
    }
);
```

Now, my question is:

How can I have Angular detect current section in the viewport and then have a single button with `ng-click` to scroll to the next section in the array of `$scope.ids`.

Also, once at the bottom, have angular detect the bottom, and change `ng-click` to back-to-top.

I can't have any jQuery dependency, and I should have mentioned probably that I'm just learning AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <a ng-click="gotoSection("Section1")">Go to Section</a>
  <a id="Section1"></a>

 $scope.gotoSection= function(id) {
          // set the location.hash to the id of
          // the element you wish to scroll to.
          $location.hash(id);

          // call $anchorScroll()
          $anchorScroll();
        };
```

Comment: If only everything was that simple. If you read my question above, that was not the issue. I know how to use anchorscroll for navigation, but the issue is that I need the scroll down/back to top function on one single fixed button. Thanks for contribution though.